# Is there a way to check if a value is within a row in SQL?

Tags: sql

Right now I am working with a data set of last names and I am trying to get all the hyphenated last names. I am wondering if there is a query that would return all the last names that contain a hyphen in them? I imagine it would be like `WHERE DC.KEYNAME INCLUDES '-'` or something like that. Thank you!

Comment: I guess something like `WHERE DC.KEYNAME like '%-%'` should solve this. Would be helpful to know the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a standard and has many implementations like Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and MySQL. It would help to know which version you are using.

I know SQL Server has a `LIKE` keyword that will do exactly what you want. You could use the filter

`WHERE dc.KeyName LIKE '%-%'`

The `%` is a wildcard, so here you would get anything with `-` anywhere in the `keyname`. If you want to filter for values starting with `-` you could use `'-%'` or for ending with that, `'%-'`